# Get perf events at 1ms granularity

Tags: linux, perf

I have an executable (runs for 2 seconds) for which I want to record events **cache-misses** and **cycles** every 1ms (I want to see what percentage of cycles are wasted in cache-misses every 1ms). That should give me a total of 2000 samples of both events. However, I have a few doubts regarding the same:

1. Is it true that `perf stat` incurs significant overhead at sub 100ms granularities (and therefore, it is better to use `perf record`)?
2. How do I extract the 2 events (cache-misses, cycles) from the `perf.data` file?

I tried doing it using `perf stat`, but it only provides 10ms granularity. I have generate a `perf.data` file using the command `perf record -e cache-misses,cycles -F 1000 <executable>`. But I am not sure how to extract the event details for each of the 2000 samples from the `perf.data` file.

Comment: https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html: `perf record`, then `perf report` or `perf script`. If that's not what you want, please clarify

Comment: @knittl The `perf stat` at 10 ms granularity gives results like
`1.202403492        388,227,957      cycles
1.202403492            216,331         cache-misses`
My expectation is to get similar output from the `perf record`  at a 1ms granularity.